# Render Html From Database to Asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I have an Html string which is stored in a Database . I fetch this string and try to render it through a literal control, but it is rendering the complete HTML code in that literal again. I have tried html encoding as well but it still fails.

My text Stored in Database is like this :

```
<p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Leela Palace Udaipur is a business-friendly property     located in Udaipur's Lake Pichola neighborhood, close to Lake Palace, Jag Niwas, and Jagdish Temple. Additional points of interest include City Palace and Crystal Gallery. </p>
```

But when I view the page it is same as above.

Please help me to find the solution. I am not using MVC

Comment: do you want to display it in a div? or any other HTML tag?

Answer (score 2):

Best way, Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.Text)`.

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Set the [LiteralMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) of your LiteralControl to **PassThrough**:

```
<asp:LiteralControl ID="yourHtml" runat="server" LiteralMode="PassThrough"></asp:LiteralControl>
```

From MSDN:

> If you specify PassThrough, the entire contents of the Text property
>   are passed to the device or browser without making any modifications

**Warning:** I hope you are confident of the HTML in the database that nothing malicious could *ever* creep in, because this is dangerous.

Comment: Again the Complete HTMl Rendered    <asp:Literal ID="Literal5" runat="server" Text="<%#: Item.hotelDescription %>" Mode="PassThrough" />

Comment: again i got the same text :   <p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Leela Palace Udaipur is a business-friendly property located in Udaipur's Lake Pichola neighborhood, close to Lake Palace, Jag Niwas, and Jagdish Temple. Additional points of interest include City Palace and Crystal Gallery. </p>

Comment: You might want to check `Item.hotelDescription` to see if it is already encoded

Comment: this is my database string : <p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Leela Palace Udaipur is a business-friendly property located in Udaipur's Lake Pichola neighborhood, close to Lake Palace, Jag Niwas, and Jagdish Temple. Additional points of interest include City Palace and Crystal Gallery. </p>

Comment: It is not encoded it directly coming from Linq :  hbase.hotelDescription = hotel.PropertyDescription;

Comment: i guess the content coming in the Item.hotelDescription field is already encoded. That is why you are viewing the encoded data..

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of `Literal`.

Comment: Mode property value is transform

Comment: @jayeshbabel : Set the mode as 'PassThrough'

Comment: I have used a Placeholder and use DataBind Method.